# Angularjs having multiple views with same controller and only run the controller once?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

Right now I have two separate views that I want to be able to controll in one controller.

However, at the moment, the controller get's run twice. Is there anyway to connect multiple views to the same controller but only have the controller run once?

I know I will probably have set up a factory to share the $scope data, but the goal is to not gather the data twice.

```
.state('cloud', {
    url: '/cloud',
    views: { 
        'main': { templateUrl: 'main.html', controller: 'cloud' },
        'second': { templateUrl: 'second.html', controller: 'cloud' }
    }
})
```

Comment: Either use a service that each controller calls (and cache the request/data in the service). Or create an uber controller (not recommended) at the common ancestor element

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The controller get's run twice because within "cloud" state you defined two views and both views having the same controller.

so, when both views gets loaded the controller called twice.

but if you want to called the controller once you have to defined separate  controller for both views.